# How to restrict zero at second position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

In the below code the text box is restricting zero at starting position. But I want to allow only one zero at first position but not more than one. here is the example

Eg:- 0.1012400==> correct

000.4545000==>not correct

0154==> correct

00154 ==> not correct

```js
$('input#abc').keypress(function(e){ 
 if (this.selectionStart == 0 && (e.which == 48 || e.which == 46 )){
      return false;
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="abc">
```

Comment: I'm not sure why `0154` would be correct. If it's a number you want you could use the input type [number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply test if there is 2 consecutive zero at the start and if yes you remove one:

```js
$('input#abc').on('keypress keydown keyup',function(e){ 
 var v = $(this).val();
 if(v.length >=2 && v[0]=='0' && v[1]=='0') {
    $(this).val(v.substring(1));
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="abc">
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a code if you want to consider the minus sign at the start:

```js
$('input#abc').on('keypress keydown keyup', function(e) {
  var v = $(this).val();
  if (v.length >= 2 && v[0] == '0' && v[1] == '0') {
    $(this).val(v.substring(1));
  } else if (v.length >= 3 && v[0] == '-' && v[1] == '0' && v[2] == '0') {
    $(this).val('-' + v.substring(2));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="abc">
```

Comment: I think you should also check for sign as OP's first example has `-` in it. So i guess `-` sign should be checked as well

Answer (score 0):

You could check the final string like

```
$('input#abc').on('change', function () {
     console.log(this.value.indexOf('00') === 0);
});
```